# Saving Multiple Html Sources in R

Tags: r, rvest

I have created the following code

```
library('XML')
library('rvest')

links <- c('https://www.google.com/', 
           'https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US', 
           'https://news.google.com/news/u/0/headlines?hl=en&ned=us')

for (i in 1:3){
  html_object <- read_html(links[i])
  write_xml(html_object, file="test.html")
}
```

I want to save all of these files as html files, but my current code is only saving one. I am guessing that it keeps rewriting the same file 3 times for this example. How would I make it so that it does not rewrite the same file? Ideally, I would like the file name for these html files to be their url link, but I am unable to figure out how to do that with multiple links. For example, my end result should be three HTML files titled 'https://google.com/', 'https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US', and 'https://news.google.come/news/u/0/headlines?h1-en&ned=us'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `paste0()` to create your filename in the for-loop?

```
for(i in 1:length(links)){
  html_object  <- read_html(links[i])
  somefilename <- paste0("filename_", i, ".html")
  write_xml(html_object, file = somefilename)
}
```